# Changing brush size in Android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, paint, brush

How to change the size of the brush without changing the size of the previous strokes? When I set the size of the stroke, it automatically changes size of the strokes that are already created.

Comment: Strokes havn't their own size, it is Paint which determines strokes size. If You want to draw Stroke of different size use another Paint for it.

Comment: Can u show ur code? How its changing strokes of paths are previously created? I guess you are using current paint object (which has latest larger stroke size) to draw previous paths too..!!

Comment: Sure, i have reposted the question with code on a different page. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649736/android-canvas-paint-changing-brush-size-of-android-canvas-brush-changes-siz . Thanks for the help!